# Как отобразить mini-карту с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, карты, map

С помощью Конструктора карт я сгенирировал код.

Вопрос в том, как на клик по текстовому полю, отобразить карту.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. человек заходит на сайт, видит адрес текста, кликает на него и тут же появляется (картинка-сноска) карты.

Буду благодарен любому работающему примеру-коду.

Comment: Есть геоссылка, она повторяет ваш функционал если вы таким образом хотите показать адрес https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geolink . Но её внешний вид нельзя изменить.

Comment: Как вариант создайте элемент спойлер заголовком спойлера будет собственно адрес , а в тело спойлера разместите готовую миникарту адреса. 
В итоге получиться текстовая строка(адрес) по клику на которую откроется спойлер с картой. Если еще добавить js  тогда спойлер будет прятаться при клике на др. текст с адресом или просто если кликнуть в "некуда" то спойлер снова закроется

Comment: Используйте jquery функцию show() : http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<details><summary>Россия Москва ул.Стаковеровская 26</summary> ТУТ КАРТА</details>
```

Comment: Добавить получилось , вопрос в том, как сделать показ всплывающего окна вверх, ибо оно улетает вниз, под footer.

Comment: тут уже надо стили ковырять детально.